# iOS Generic swift closure

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to Pass a generic model object in swift.

Currently I have a closure that have to return the Model object as below

```
  completionHandler = ([ModelObject]?, Error?) -> Void
```

Method calling

```
func method1( onCompletion: @escaping completionHandler) -> Void {

}
```

I want to make a generic completionhandler that can pass different model  instead of specific Model. 
Note:- all model object conform to Codable protocol as below

```
struct ModelObject: Codable {
}
```

//===== Edit======

```
func method1<M: Codable>( onCompletion: @escaping (M?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let items = try? decoder.decode(ModelObject.self, from: data)
            onCompletion(items, nil)// error in this line Cannot convert value of type 'ModelObject?' to expected argument type '_?'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your method something like:

```
func method1<Model: Codable>(onCompletion: @escaping (Model?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let itemObj = try? decoder.decode(Model.self, from: data)
    onCompletion(itemObj, nil)
}
```

And if you have your struct like:

```
struct ModelObject: Codable {
}
```

you can call this method like:

```
method1 { (model: ModelObject?, error) in

}
```

You have another struct like:

```
struct AnotherModelObject: Codable {
}
```

You can call it like:

```
method1 { (model: AnotherModelObject?, error) in

}
```

Comment: This solution is not correct if he wants to transfer several variables of different types

Comment: @Vyacheslav can you give an example? like what?

Comment: `[ModelObject(), AnotherModelObject()]` as a result array

Comment: @Vyacheslav I'm sure that's not a Generics case, In generics we have to specify the type at the compile time. He asked for a Generic solution.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, can you tell me how to call this completion handler inside the method. I am getting error Cannot convert value of type 'ModelObjectName?' to expected argument type '_?'

Comment: @Ekra Can you add some code, like what are you trying to do in this method, then I can update the answer.

Comment: @Mukesh :- if  Model.self and <Model: Codable> is same name(Model class) than  how it will be a generic solution. OR I missed something as when you called the same method for different Model object do we need pass actual Model name ?

Comment: @Ekra here `Model` is Generic type use can rename it to anything like `T`. and then use `T.self`. It will be converted to the type you used when calling the method. like in my case first time it will be `ModelObject` and second time it will be `AnotherModelObject`. It is determined by the type you specify in the closure at calling time like `method1 { (model: ModelObject?, error) in

}`

Comment: If I modify your method then it will be: `func method1<M: Codable>( onCompletion: @escaping (M?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let items = try? decoder.decode(M.self, from: data)
            onCompletion(items, nil)
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163791/discussion-between-mukesh-and-ekra).

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the protocol inside another struct or you can use a custom container.

```
protocol Container { }
struct Storage {
    let model: Codable
}
struct ModelObject: Codable, Container {
}
enum Result<T> {
    case data(result: T)
}
typealias completionHandler = ([Storage]?, Error?) -> Void

func method1(onCompletion: @escaping completionHandler) -> Void {
    onCompletion([Storage(model:ModelObject())], nil)
}
func method2(onCompletion: @escaping ([Result<Codable>]) -> Void) -> Void {
    onCompletion([Result.data(result: ModelObject() as Codable)])
}
method1 { result, _ in
    print(result![0].model)
}
method2 { result in
    print(result[0])
}
```